# Are 'feminism' and 'feminist' part of the same lexeme, or two different lexemes?

Tags: semantics, lexemes

I get the impression they're two different lexemes, but would like some opinions!

Answer (score 2):

If "feminist" and "feminism" are different forms of the same word, one might expect the following to be interpretable and acceptable English:

> I support feminism, but I wouldn't want to be one.
>   All my friends are feminists, so naturally I support it, also.

Comment: I've never been interested in Communism, but then I've never met many of them.

Comment: I lean towards linguistics nativism, but many people aren't.